# Downloading a html div content in form of an image

Tags: html, svg

I am displaying a table with some data in my jsp. I want to add a download button on top of it , clicking on which will download the whole table in the form of an image. Please help me with this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() { 
$("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            // Convert and download as image 
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
            $("#img-out").append(canvas);
            // Clean up 
            //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
    });
});
```

});

check out this fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/)

Click on **Save PNG** right click to save image as option and your good to go.